# Upload Image to Database From DetailsView Insert Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, detailsview, sqldatasource

I am attempting to upload an image to a database via a DetailsView containing an UploadFile control in the Edit Item template.

I have a stored procedure which handles the upload to a SQLServer DB which expects two parameters: AuthorName, varchar(20) and AuthorImage, varbin(20).

The DetailsView is associated with a SQLDataSource: Authors. The Authors data source has the stored procedure as the Insert Command.

I can grab the binary data from the UploadFile control during the ItemInserting event but I am at a loss as to how to attach the byte array to the AuthorImage parameter.

Any and all assistance appreciated and if possible answers in C# please.

Answer (score 0):

On asp.net you can find the "Personal Site Starter Kit" who handles your problem. You can find it on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/personal/)